# Opencart Getting Customers' telephone no

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I don't know how to get an array of Customers' telephone numbers in Opencart 2.0.2.0

I have found how to get email of customers' by looking at contact.php in the `controller` folder :

```
$results = $this - > model_sale_customer - > getCustomers($customer_data);

foreach($results as $result) {
  $emails[] = $result['email'];
}
```

Which one of these implementations will work? If neither then please help me.

1st.

```
$results = $this - > model_sale_customer - > getCustomers($customer_data);

foreach($results as $result) {
  $contact[] = $result['telephone'];
}
```

2nd

```
$results = $this - > model_sale_customer - > getCustomers($customer_data);

foreach($results as $result) {
  $contact[] = $result['contact'];
}
```

Comment: the first one should work, if you trace the function `getCustomers` @ class `ModelSaleCustomer` located in the file `<OC_ROOT>/admin/model/sale/customer.php` you will find that it returns all the columns in the table `customer` including the field `telephone`

Comment: if you are so confused about it, why don't you just try them both and see which one works :D